# Combinations - pairing up people from array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations

I've got a combinations question. I have designed this "Secret Santa" app that lets users join gift-groups in which they exchange gifts for a set dollar amount. When a user logs in, he can see all the groups he is in, along with the members in each group. Now, I want to design the groups so that each group randomly pairs up people for gift giving. I want to the algorithm to work so that I'm guaranteed that everyone in the group both gets assigned a person to give gifts to, and a person to receive gifts from. So for example, if a group has three members, `[A, B, C]`, I want `A->B, B->C, C->A`.

Any ideas how that could work? It doesn't matter if it will use just the one, or two arrays. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: So what's the issue? Have you tried anything?

Comment: so simply make a ring exchange.

Comment: This question is about algorithms and not programming languages. All programming language tags should be removed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik may be learningjs888 need an algorithm in  java or js

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky If that is true, the question should be closed as "too broad" because it is a request to write code from scratch, in two languages.

Comment: Please look at round-robin tournament scheduling algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm

Comment: Well, that may be the case. I'm simply asking for help as I am a front end designer, and don't know the logic needed for this to be accomplished. As far as the languages goes, I don't need two, I simply tagged JS & Java as ANY solution would do. @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets `n` - number of persons in a group
So just make pairs of `{persons[i], persons[(i+1)%n]}` for all persons

Comment: First perform a random shuffle, though. Otherwise, this is fine.